# Why we need to create artifacts when set up CI/CD life cycle

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, artifact

What are the advantages of creating artifacts and what are the use-cases of them?

I'm trying to set up a CI/CD example with AWS Codebuild and make its artifact output to a S3 bucket. But I am not sure about the objective and the use-cases of them.

Answer (score 1):

Some common artifacts from a CI/CD pipelines are distribution packages eg zip, exe, test reports, Docker or VM images, documentation.